# Importing library once for a python module

Tags: python, module, python-import

I want to structure `imports` of my python module/package, namely I have several `*.py` files in my module. All of them use:

```
 import numpy as np
```

in some pf them I use:

```
import pandas as pd
```

can I set the global import for my python module, and say that it uses `numpy as np` in all the `*.py` files of the module.
I tried something in `__init__.py` but it didn't work as expected. Is it anyhow reasonable to make global imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this, it is fundamentally opposed to the way Python works.

Comment: thanks. thats what I expected. But if I am just naughty rebel who does not obey rules, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Still not, and for very good reasons that will possibly make sense to you someday...

Answer (score 0):

Warning:- Do not use this at home.Not a good practice
You can Do it by importing all your libraries into a single file. For example:-

library.py

```
import numpy as np
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
```

And then import this file in your code files

main.py

```
from library import *

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Technically true, but a _very_ bad idea - cf pep08's section on star imports

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers True, But according to OP, he wants to be a naughty rebel who does not obey rules.

Comment: Yes I seen this too. Well, as long as I don't have to maintain his code base, the OP can be as much of a "rebel" as he wants, but since there are quite some newbies reading SO I felt the need to warn them that most "rules" (let's say "best practices") result from experience. Just like when you tell your kids to NOT try to jump from the roof using an umbrella as parachute... From personal experience, my mum was right; it _does_ hurt.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I added a warning for newbies before trying this at home